# huggingface transformer CTRL model can not work for generation text

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, huggingface-transformers

`torch` ver: `1.8.1+cu102`
`transformers` ver: `4.4.2`

I adopt the example codes from https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/text-generation/run_generation.py

to generate text by using ctrl.
here is the head part of my codes:

```
import torch
from transformers import CTRLTokenizer, CTRLLMHeadModel
tokenizer = CTRLTokenizer.from_pretrained('ctrl')
model = CTRLLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('ctrl')

encoded_prompt = tokenizer.encode("Links Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=False)
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in
----> 1 encoded_prompt = tokenizer.encode("Links Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=False)

~/yanan/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in encode(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, return_tensors, **kwargs) 2030 stride=stride, 2031 return_tensors=return_tensors,
-> 2032 **kwargs, 2033 ) 2034

~/yanan/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs) 2355 return_length=return_length, 2356 verbose=verbose,
-> 2357 **kwargs, 2358 ) 2359

~/yanan/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in _encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs) 458 return_special_tokens_mask=return_special_tokens_mask, 459 return_length=return_length,
--> 460 verbose=verbose, 461 ) 462

~/yanan/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in prepare_for_model(self, ids, pair_ids, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, prepend_batch_axis,
**kwargs) 2792 padding=padding_strategy.value, 2793 pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
-> 2794 return_attention_mask=return_attention_mask, 2795 ) 2796

~/yanan/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in pad(self, encoded_inputs, padding, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_attention_mask, return_tensors, verbose) 2591 else: 2592 raise ValueError(
-> 2593 f"type of {first_element} unknown: {type(first_element)}. " 2594 f"Should be one of a python, numpy, pytorch or tensorflow object." 2595 )

ValueError: type of None unknown: <class 'NoneType'>. Should be one of a python, numpy, pytorch or tensorflow object.
```